# Razorpay Payment Gateway throws error while installing via composer

Tags: magento, magento2

I have tried so many times to install razorpay payment gateway via below link https://razorpay.com/docs/ecommerce-plugins/magento/2.x/

Also I tried manually but it shows error below..

Problem 1 - colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract v1.3.4 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement. - colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract v1.3.4 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement. - colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract v1.3.4 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement. - Installation request for colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract (locked at v1.3.4) -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].

Putty Login and run the command  : php bin/magento composer install

2.) php bin/magento composer upgrade

composer require razorpay/magento
bin/magento module:enable Razorpay_Magento

bin/magento module:enable Razorpay_Magento
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

But when I try this it disabled my whole setup of magento.

Razorpay successfully setup

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the razorpay setup. Run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Install it from latest release here, https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-magento/releases. Use step for "code.zip" installation.

Comment: Looks like there are some issue in your  PHP version compatibility with Magento2. You can try to resolve it first. Suggestions
https://github.com/magento-engcom/php-7.2-support/issues/1
https://mage2.pro/t/topic/5278

Answer (score -1):

Run the following command before installation of Razorpay plugin php bin/magento setup:di:compile and after zip install as well

Let me know the outcome

Comment: Compilation was started.
Proxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 58.0 Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 60.0 MiRepositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 60.0 MiB[forevergujju@bh-in-35 public_html]$

Comment: Looks like the Magento code did not compile properly.
Kindly check with your Magento installation.